# Are boosted machine learning methods robust against low probable feature combinations when predicting?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, causality, boosting

I would like to use machine learning methods in the potential outcome framework, that is, simulating outcome for all observations under different values of a specific predictor, while keeping all other features fixed.

The problem with this approach is that some feature combinations are simply unlikely to happen. For example, for healthcare-associated infections, it is known the great importance of central vascular catheters in driving up the risk. But if I would like to simulate the individual risk change if all the patients in a hospital would have the catheter compared to not having it, I have to keep in account that is very unlikely that, say, psychiatry ward patients would ever get a vascular catheterization.

Causal estimation methodologies use techniques like propensity score or observations reweighting to account for this phenomenon.

Formally, using a linear model dummy example, given a variable of interest X which I set artificially to 1 for all observations, and Z a set of covariates, for each observation $i$, it be would somthing like: 
$$(Yi|do:X=1)=\beta_0 + \beta_x(X=1)p(X=1|Z_i) + \beta_zZ_i$$
That is, when $p(X=1|Z_i)$ is zero, the effect of the of the X disappears (NB: I'm not an expert of counterfactual methods).

Normally one would have to compute $p(X=1|Z_i)$ separately.

Since ML boosting techniques, like xgboost, work on observation reweighting, I was wondering if such models already keep in account the plausibility of feature values coexistence, by giving more weight to highly predictive combinations of predictors values and less weight to unseen (because unlikely) ones.

Comment: I don't understand, boosting weights observations not variables, so every generated observation will be plausible, as long as the observation is plausible.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. I start with a database of real data and I train a xgb model on it. Then, I take all the observation and change a variable of interest first (eg) to 1 and make a prediction for each observation ($Y_{x1}|X=1$), and then to 0 and again I make the predictions ($Y_{x0}|X=0$). Finally, I want to compare $Y_{x1}$ and $Y_{x0}$. But, In the real word I cannot just change X freely because X depends on some other variable set Z, so eg. it's unlikely to see $X=0$ for some combination of Z. I was wondering if xgb reweighting method take this in consideration.

Comment: Practically, in a logistic setting, I would expect xgb to predict 0 (on logit scale) or just predict the the grand mean in case of totally unplausible association of X (set by me) and Z (as observed). In a linear setting it would be something like $Y=\beta_0+\beta_x(X=1)*p(X=1|Z)+\beta_zZ$ that is, the effect of an X artificially set to 1 would be rescaled by the probabilty of observing X=1 given a specific combination of covariates.